# Django collectstatic does not collect media files from react npm build folder

Tags: django, favicon, collectstatic, npm-build

I have a frontend react app, after using `npm run build` it creates build folder with:

- build

  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - `service-woker.js`
  - static

After using django's `python manage.py collectstatic` I noticed what django has done was that it pulls out only the static folder, favicon.ico is not pulled out. So, my website icon doesn't work.

In my index.html, `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`

In my settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/web/home/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'home/static/'
```

In chrome inspect in the headers element:

```
<link rel="icon" href="./home/favicon.ico">
```

How do I get it to display my web icon. Thankyou!

Comment: how do your static setting look like-> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: @iklinac added settings.py

Comment: how do you serve your files on production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear in documentation that Django collectstatic looks only for files in folders that are set in

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build/static')
]
```

> This will copy all files from your static folders into the STATIC_ROOT
>   directory.

your favicon is not in any of listed staticfiles directiories

---

Second thing is that Django static files are  only accessible from full STATIC_URL path ( you cannot use just .home/ path)

Fix would be one of following

- to simply add icon inside static folder
- use [ngnix](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) to serve static files and add proper blocks ( prefered )
- change STATIC_ROOT='/var/www/web/home/' and STATIC_URL = 'home/' ( note this way index.html and rest of files in home would be accessible as staticfiles)